# Learn Clojure: NullPointerException on triplicate

Tags: clojure

I'm taking the [beginner tutorial](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions) on the Clojure official site.

One exercise asks you to do the following:

> 7) Define a function `triplicate` which takes another function and calls it three times, without any arguments.

Which I solved as follows:

```
(defn triplicate [f] ((f) (f) (f)))
```

The problem is that when used, at the very end a `NullPointerException` is thrown, for which I cannot identify the cause.

```
user=> (triplicate #(println "hello, world"))
hello, world
hello, world
hello, world
NullPointerException   user/triplicate (NO_SOURCE_FILE:115)
```

The following is the output of `pst`, should it be useful:

```
user=> (pst)
NullPointerException
        user/triplicate (NO_SOURCE_FILE:145)
        user/triplicate (NO_SOURCE_FILE:145)
        user/eval376 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:146)
        user/eval376 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:146)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7062)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7025)
        clojure.core/eval (core.clj:3206)
        clojure.core/eval (core.clj:3202)
        clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print--8572/fn--8575 (main.clj:243)
        clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print--8572 (main.clj:243)
        clojure.main/repl/fn--8581 (main.clj:261)
        clojure.main/repl (main.clj:261)
nil
```

What could the cause be?

Comment: Since your assignment does not state the return value, this could as well be just sideeffects, so you could also do `(defn triplicate [f] (f) (f) (f))`, which then returns the last result.  Or add a `nil` at the end to even prevent that.  A `defn` has an impliciy `do` around the body.

Comment: @cfrick Makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the clearest solution is:

```
(do
  (f) 
  (f)
  (f))
```

Evaluating multiple expressions is the sole purpose of `do`. If you don't want the cut-and-paste repetition, the best way is:

```
(dotimes [i 3]
  (f))
```

Using the vector form slightly obscures the repetition goal and implies you want 3 of the return value of `(f)`.

---

Footnote:  I would never use `juxt` as it is an obscure function that will leave most people scratching their heads and running to [The Clojure CheatSheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) to look up its definition.

Comment: `(def triplicate #(dotimes [i 3] (%)))` seems very readable and succinct. Thanks!

Comment: wait! but it doesn't return the result of the function call.. so it is worthy only for side effects.. `(triplicate #(inc 10)) => nil`. Also i would argue about `juxt`: since clojure is the functional language, such things as `juxt`, `comp`, `partial`, `apply` etc  is the natural way of programming for it, while side effecting and imperative things (like `dotimes`, `while`...) although being totally understandable for FP beginner coming from other languages, are there for the narrow range of special occasions, and should be avoided otherwise. This answer seems counter-educating to me

Comment: I don't often use `dotimes`, since it only makes sense with side-effecting code. However, calling `(f)` 3 times in a row in a `(do ...)` form implies that `(f)` is side-effecting (since the results of the first 2 calls to `(f)` are discarded).

Answer (score 4):

```
(defn triplicate [f] ((f) (f) (f)))
```

Which returns: 
`(nil nil nil)` the thing is **nil** is not a function. Calling nil causes **NullPointerException**.

You could write like this:

```
(defn triplicate [f] [(f) (f) (f)])
;;=> [nil nil nil] which is fine, because you are keeping nils in a vector.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I decided to mark @leetwinski's answer as accepted because of the extra information, but your answer is just as valid.

Answer (score 4):

the problem is in this part: `((f) (f) (f))`

this form means: "call function f and then call it's result as function with 2 arguments: result of `f` call and result of `f` call"

you can fix it with `[(f) (f) (f)]`

or just use `juxt`:

```
user> (def triplicate #(juxt % % %))
#'user/triplicate

user> ((triplicate #(println "hello")))
;;=> hello
;;=> hello
;;=> hello
[nil nil nil]
```